# html imports like layout engine

Tags: javascript

On php, the implementation looks very simple, suppose we have files: header.html, body.html. Then our code index.php will look something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
  <? = require(' header.html ')?>
    <div class = "main">
      <? = require(' body.html ')?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
<html>   
  <body>
    <link rel = "import" href = "header.html">
    <div class = "main">
      <link rel = "import" href = "body.html">
    </div>

   <script>
      / * A magic js function that replaces <link rel = "import"> with the content of the html document * /
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS I understand that this will work on a very limited number of browsers.

Comment: yes possible take a look at webpack and html webpack loader

Comment: A great solution already suggested. Alternatively, you can use ajax to load html content.

Comment: Sort of like iframes done with client-side scripting? ... Why?

Answer (score 0):

A number of JavaScript template engines are available.
[Handlebars.js](https://handlebarsjs.com/) and [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) use curly brackets for variables. 
[Jade/Pug](https://github.com/pugjs/pug) dispenses with brackets altogether.

You could [build your own template library](https://jonsuh.com/blog/javascript-templating-without-a-library/) and use any format you want. The spectrum of browsers that it works on would depend on how far back in history you're willing to support.

Whereas PHP enables you to import static headers and footers, with JavaScript you're more likely to have a static template with the header and footer built in, and import the body content dynamically. We see this a lot with [lazy loading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading) content on sites like Google image search and Pinterest.